# Including and understanding package CoverPage

Tags: covers

I included the  `\usepackage{CoverPage}` in my document but I have no idea in inserting my data entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the CoverPage package documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/coverpage), you need to provide a `BiBTeX` file. So if you main file is called `TeX-SE.tex` (as in this example), then you need to provide a `TeX-SE.BibTeX.txt` file. Once you do that then you automatically get a cover as:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `filecontents` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents)
  was used to set up a file to read for this test case.
  It is not needed in you actual use case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{filecontents}%% <--- Commented out to prevent overwriting this file
\begin{filecontents*}{TeX-SE.BibTeX.txt}
@article{small,
author = {Algosig},
title = {A small paper},
journal = {The journal of small papers},
year = 2014,
volume = {-1},
note = {to appear},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{CoverPage}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked, but how can I add more attributes like logos, and how can I use other styles of cover pages?

Comment: @algosig: Please refer to the documentation: added a link to it in the answer.